# How do I create larger polygons out of a smaller polygons

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I would like to transform the following list of polygons:

```
[
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 0, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 32, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 64, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 256, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 288, y: 0}
]
```

Into a list where the adjacent polygons are joined as follows:

```
[
  %{height: 32, width: 96, x: 0, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 64, x: 256, y: 0}
]
```

I've tried using Enum.reduce_while as follows:

```
Enum.reduce_while(polys, 0, fn poly, max_x ->
  if poly.x - max_x <= 32, do: {:cont, max_x + 32}, else: {:halt, max_x}
end)
```

That works to give me the first polygon, but how do I get the subsequent polygons and is it possible to get all of them in 1 pass?

Comment: Are the second and third polygons considered adjacent? Their `x` is separated by `64` but the width/height are only 32.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that mistake out @Dogbert. I have edited my question.

The only gap should be between the third and fourth polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a perfect use-case for [`Enum.chunk_while/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_while/4):

```rb
input = [
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 0, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 32, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 64, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 256, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 288, y: 0}
]

chunk_fun = fn
  i, [] -> {:cont, i}
  %{width: iw, x: ix}, %{height: ah, width: aw, x: ax, y: ay}
       when ax + aw == ix ->
    {:cont, %{height: ah, width: aw + iw, x: ax, y: ay}}
  %{height: ih, y: iy}, %{height: ah, width: aw, x: ax, y: ay}
       when ay + ah == iy ->
    {:cont, %{height: ah + ih, width: aw, x: ax, y: ay}}
  i, acc -> {:cont, acc, i}
end

after_fun = fn
  [] -> {:cont, []}
  acc -> {:cont, acc, []}
end

input
|> Enum.chunk_while([], chunk_fun, after_fun)
|> IO.inspect()

#⇒ [%{height: 32, width: 96, x: 0, y: 0},
#   %{height: 32, width: 64, x: 256, y: 0}]
```

Please note, that the example above also handles the y-axis joins. The example is interesting due to the unusual use of a map instance as an accumulator.

Comment: I have selected this answer as correct one using https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers as a guide. The solution by @Dogbert also works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Enum.reduce` here. `Enum.reduce_while` is meant for cases when you want to stop processing the list further based on some condition. You do want to process the whole list in this case.

What I do is collect polygons in the accumulator, starting with a list with only the first polygon. Then, in each reduction, I check whether the previous polygon's `x` + `width` is the same as the new polygon's `x`. If it is, I merge the polygons by adding the widths, if not I prepend the polygon.

The list is collected in reverse so I use `Enum.reverse` after the reduction.

```
[
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 0, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 32, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 64, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 256, y: 0},
  %{height: 32, width: 32, x: 288, y: 0}
]
|> Enum.reduce(nil, fn
  x, nil ->
    [x]

  x, [h | t] ->
    if h.x + h.width == x.x do
      [%{h | width: x.width + h.width} | t]
    else
      [x, h | t]
    end
end)
|> Enum.reverse()
|> IO.inspect()
```

Output:

```
[%{height: 32, width: 96, x: 0, y: 0}, %{height: 32, width: 64, x: 256, y: 0}]
```

Comment: [`Enum.chink_while/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_while/4) looks more idiomatic to me here.

Comment: Thanks, using reduce definitely seemed like a good approach, but I wasn't able to get this to work.

Comment: @Catharz this is a bit unfair; this code perfectly works for the example data you provided.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @mudasobwa. I retried this solution and it worked as per the requirements. Me not getting it to work wasn't a problem with this answer. It was a problem with me trying to use it in iex. I've voted up both answers.